# cannot convert from 'System.Management.EnumerationOptions' to 'System.IO.SearchOption

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer, .net-framework-version

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.Management;

namespace test_code
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
           //folderDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (folderDlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Has different framework dependend implementations 
            // in order to handle unauthorized access to subfolders
            RenamePngFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);
        }
        private void RenamePngFiles(string directoryPath)
        {
            int fileNameSuffixCounter = 1;
            foreach (string originalFullFileName in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png", new EnumerationOptions()))
            {
                // The new file name without path
                var newFileName = $"{System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFullFileName)}#{fileNameSuffixCounter++}{System.IO.Path.GetExtension(originalFullFileName)}";

                FileSystem.RenameFile(originalFullFileName, newFileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my code and I am not sure why i am not able to remove the above error. I tried all sorts of namespace and i cannot of get rid of it. I am using .netframework 4.7.2.
AS you can see all I am trying to do is rename all the files in a folder including subfolder to append with # and a number which keep on increasing depending on the number of files in a folder.

Comment: Remove `, new EnumerationOptions()` this all together, or use the `SearchOption` enum if you need it

Comment: how, can i do that an you post it as solution. please..

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png")`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_

Comment: so i removed the foreach code line like this `foreach (string originalFullFileName in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png"))`. Now no errros but when i run the application its not renaming the file

Comment: I didn't say remove the foreach :/ --- `foreach (string originalFullFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png"))`

Comment: ok i change it.. please see my updated code at pastebin.. but when i look inside the folders no file gets renamed. No change at all https://pastebin.com/SHXFzV25

Comment: This is now a completely different question :/ Have you debugged this to check if the paths are right and correct ?

Comment: ok, can you please help. Iam trying this for a long time.. When i give a single folder with lots of PNG files inside then it renames all files to #1, #2.. etc. but when i have multiple subfolders inside a folder then this renaming doesnt work

Comment: `foreach (string originalFullFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories))` do note `SearchOption.AllDirectories` and here is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined with the comments above, I made the following changes.

Updated：

Modify all png files in the selectedPath.

```
RenameAllPngFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);
```

**The following are custom functions:**

Rename all png files :

```
private void RenameAllPngFiles(string directoryPath) {
    RenameCurrentPng(directoryPath);
    foreach (var item in GetDirectoryInfos(directoryPath)) {
        RenameCurrentPng(item.FullName);
    }
}
```

Rename all png files in the current directory:

```
private void RenameCurrentPng(string directoryPath) {
    int fileNameSuffixCounter = 1;
    foreach (string originalFullFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png")) {
        // The new file name without path
        var newFileName = $"{System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFullFileName)}#{fileNameSuffixCounter++}{System.IO.Path.GetExtension(originalFullFileName)}";
        FileSystem.RenameFile(originalFullFileName, newFileName);
    }
}
```

Get the addresses of all subfolders :

```
private DirectoryInfo[] GetDirectoryInfos(string directoryPath) {
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
    DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories("*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    return directories;
}
```

**If you have questions about my code, please comment below and I will follow up.**

Comment: when irun your codes, only main subfolders are naming.. nothing inside gets renamed. I dont want subfolder to get remaned. Only the .png files insider the subfolder want to get renamed to #1. Please see my paste bin code https://pastebin.com/SPAfM6wZ  Also, i have multiple subfolders insider main folder. also multiple sub folders in subfoldders.. so I want the program to crawl inisde to the bottom and start remaining all .png files

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant, and I will update my answer.

Comment: Please check for updates and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Comment: woow, amazing its working now. You are the master blaster

Comment: @ 
Jiale Xue - MSFT is it possible also to customize the code in such a way that, if the file name already exist #2 or #3 like that then can we skip that file??

Comment: In principle it is possible. However, if there are too many files, checking each file again may lead to a long time.